# Unseting value from array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Alright so I have been trying to unset a value from the notifications an array called "subscribers". Subscribers array is literally bunch of ObjectId's of users.

I've created this query but I keep on getting an error and I am not sure if I did it correctly or not

```
db.notifications.update({
    subscribers:{$in:[ObjectId("51a37d82f03f08f06b000019")]}, 
    last_update:{$lte : new Date(2019, 1, 1)},
    $unset:  { "subscribers": { ObjectId("51a37d82f03f08f06b000019") }},
}).limit(10);
```

Error that I am getting is

> Error: Line 9: Unexpected token (

Comment: 1) You cannot use `limit` with the update query. 2) If you want to remove element from an array you have to use `$pull` not `$unset`. 3) Your syntax is wrong. Try this `db.notifications.update(
 {
  subscribers: { $in: [ObjectId("51a37d82f03f08f06b000019")] },
  last_update: { $lte :new Date(2019, 1, 1) }
 },
  { $pull:  { "subscribers": ObjectId("51a37d82f03f08f06b000019") }},
})`

Comment: Hmm thanks but still throws an error

Answer (score 0):

To start with I'm guessing the structure of your documents is as follows?

```
db.notifications.insertMany([
    { subscribers: [ObjectId(),ObjectId()], last_update: new Date()},
    { subscribers: [ObjectId(),ObjectId()], last_update: new Date()},
    { subscribers: [ObjectId(),ObjectId()], last_update: new Date()}
]);

> db.notifications.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b84928155f"),
        "subscribers" : [
                ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b849281559"),
                ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b84928155a")
        ],
        "last_update" : ISODate("2019-05-21T16:34:20.839Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b849281560"),
        "subscribers" : [
                ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b84928155b"),
                ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b84928155c")
        ],
        "last_update" : ISODate("2019-05-21T16:34:20.839Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b849281561"),
        "subscribers" : [
                ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b84928155d"),
                ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b84928155e")
        ],
        "last_update" : ISODate("2019-05-21T16:34:20.839Z")
}
```

So let's start by finding subscriber with the ID of `ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b849281559")` within a given time from document `_id` : `ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b84928155f")`.

```
> db.notifications.find({
        last_update: { $lte: dateLessThan },
        subscribers : ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b849281559")
    }).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b84928155f"),
        "subscribers" : [
                ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b849281559"),
                ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b84928155a")
        ],
        "last_update" : ISODate("2019-05-21T16:34:20.839Z")
}
```

Now we'll change this in to an update with a $pull operator:

```
> db.notifications.update({
        last_update: { $lte: dateLessThan }, subscribers : ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b849281559")
    }, {
        $pull: {"subscribers" : ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b849281559")}
    })
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Now if we go look at our document we'll notice that the object id has now been removed from subscribers

```
> db.notifications.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b84928155f")}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b84928155f"),
        "subscribers" : [
                ObjectId("5ce4288c4c7627b84928155a")
        ],
        "last_update" : ISODate("2019-05-21T16:34:20.839Z")
}
```

This query will however only match one document, if we want it to update all documents that match the query criteria you will need to specifiy an options of `{ multi: true }`:

```
db.notifications.update({...}, {...}, { multi: true })
```

More reading:
find - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/
update - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/
$pull - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/